# how to use common variable in UNION sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How could I setup a single variable to use in the "transactions.amount > 5" part of the SQL, which is used across both sections of the below SELECT statement?  That is so I could set the value (e.g. 5 in this example) once in the query and then both sides of the UNION ALL statement could reference this?

I'm using Microsoft Access by the way, so this is an access Query.

```
SELECT transactions.title, transactions.amount, categories.title
FROM transactions LEFT JOIN (categories RIGHT JOIN [trans-cat] ON categories.ID = [trans-cat].categoryID) ON transactions.ID = [trans-cat].transactionID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select transactionID from [trans-cat] where transactions.ID = [trans-cat].transactionID ) AND transactions.amount > 5

union all

SELECT transactions.title, transactions.amount, categories.title
FROM transactions INNER JOIN (categories INNER JOIN [trans-cat] ON categories.ID = [trans-cat].categoryID) ON transactions.ID = [trans-cat].transactionID
WHERE  transactions.amount > 5
```

Comment: I don't think you can easily do this in MS Access, because you cannot put `union all` in a subquery.  You could create a view with `union all` and then use the `where` condition on that.

Comment: If you use the same parameter name (i.e. [threshold]) for both conditions the parameter will need to be specified once

Comment: thanks @cha - I didn't even think to try this (should have) - I think this will help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @cha's response:

If you use the same parameter name (i.e. [threshold]) for both conditions the parameter will need to be specified once